# Azure Blob - Read content inside folder using postman

Tags: azure, postman, azure-blob-storage

I'm really new to this Azure Blob, sorry if I ask noob question.

I'm successfully called Azure Blob using postman but I cant read content inside the folder.

[image]

[image]

Is there anything that I missed.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Just change the request URL and add "Blob.txt" to the end. That should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GET Api call will not return anything as part of response unless you access any physical file which is present in the azure blob container.

Append the `Blob.txt` to the path of the container(request URL) and check.